# When uploading to playstore: ResTable header size 0x0000 is too small

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic3

When uploading to Google Playstore, I get the following error.

```
 Upload failed

Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output:

Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(582298): ResTable header size 0x0000 is too small.
ERROR: dump failed because the resource table is invalid/corrupt.
```

What does it mean? And how to fix it in ionic 3? I used [APK signer](https://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/) to sign the APK, could it be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this yourself with a tool that is part of the Android SDK called `aapt`.

- You probably already have the Android SDK, but if you don't [download it from here](https://developer.android.com/studio/). It's quite a long way down the page in a section called "Command line tools only". If you have Android Studio you already have it.
- Install the SDK
- `aapt` is usually in the `build-tools` subdirectory of the installed APK
- run the following command on your apk, either:

  - `aapt dump badging my.apk` or
  - `aapt dump xmltree my.apk AndroidManifest.xml`

You can use the commands to check whether ionic is producing a bad APK or APKSigner is corrupting it somehow.

Comment: What errors am i supposed to see? I did those commands, how to know if the apk is bad? What to look for?

Comment: If they print normally then it is a good sign the APK is ok. You might also want to try aapt2 which is in the same directory, and see if that gives any errors